# Javascript, redirect to a link retrieved by a function?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Right now I'm showing an href that redirects to a certain location, I want to redirect automatically to the same link but don't know how.

This is the link:

```
<script>
document.write('<a href="?s=' + geoip_city() + '"> Go </a>');
</script>
```

I tried with window.location but I'm messing somehow since I go literally to the name of the function.

How should I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `window.location.href` should redirect you to a new page, like this:

```
var url = geoip_city(); // url should be a valid url string
window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `window.location.href` to redirect. So assuming you have a function which returns an url:

```
function geoip_city() {
    ...
    return 'http://example.com?foo=bar';
}
```

you could redirect like this:

```
window.location.href = geoip_city();
```